# Пропали всплывающие подсказки в Xaml Forms(VS 2017)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Неожиданно пропали всплывающие подсказки на языке XAML, в том же проекте на C# они работают. Заходил в настройки - в С# IntelliSense включен, в XAML просто нет такого пункта. Как можно это починить? Компьютер и студию несколько раз перезапускал

Answer (score 0):

Подсказки также появляются при нажатии клавиш `ctrl + space`